# How to remove fadding effect in VisualizerView

Tags: android, graph, porter-duff

I am using [felix library](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer) for Bar Graph Visualization. And it is working fine. But **i only want to remove the fading effect**. Instead need a simple one Color BarGraph Animation. Just replace fading effect with Simple Color.

I tried by removing `mFadePaint` from VisualizerView but it is not Working properly then i try by replacing PorterDuffXfermode to LIGHTEN and darken and add also . but don't get the required Result.

```
public class VisualizerView extends View 
{
  private static final String TAG = "VisualizerView";

  private byte[] mBytes;
  private byte[] mFFTBytes;
  private Rect mRect = new Rect();
  private Visualizer mVisualizer;

  private Set<Renderer> mRenderers;

  private Paint mFlashPaint = new Paint();
  private Paint mFadePaint = new Paint();

  public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  {
    super(context, attrs);

    if(!this.isInEditMode())
    init();
  }

  public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public VisualizerView(Context context)
  {
    this(context, null, 0);
  }

  private void init() 
  {
    mBytes = null;
    mFFTBytes = null;

    mFlashPaint.setColor(Color.argb(122, 255, 255, 255));
    mFadePaint.setColor(Color.argb(122, 255, 255, 255));// orignal is               Color.argb(238, 255, 255, 255)); // Adjust alpha to change how quickly the image fades
    mFadePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));  //orignal mode is  MULTIPLY

    mRenderers = new HashSet<Renderer>();
  }

  /**
   * Links the visualizer to a player
   * @param player - MediaPlayer instance to link to
   */
  public void link(MediaPlayer player)
  {
    if(player == null)
    {
      throw new NullPointerException("Cannot link to null MediaPlayer");
    }

    // Create the Visualizer object and attach it to our media player.
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(player.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);

    // Pass through Visualizer data to VisualizerView
    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
          int samplingRate)
      {
        updateVisualizer(bytes);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
          int samplingRate)
      {
        updateVisualizerFFT(bytes);
      }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
        Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, true);

    // Enabled Visualizer and disable when we're done with the stream
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
      {
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
      }
    });
  }


  public void mylink()
  {
    // Create the Visualizer object and attach it to our media player.
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);

    // Pass through Visualizer data to VisualizerView
    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
          int samplingRate)
      {
        updateVisualizer(bytes);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
          int samplingRate)
      {
        updateVisualizerFFT(bytes);
      }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
        Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, true);

    // Enabled Visualizer and disable when we're done with the stream
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);

  }

  public void addRenderer(Renderer renderer)
  {
    if(renderer != null)
    {
      mRenderers.add(renderer);
    }
  }

  public void clearRenderers()
  {
    mRenderers.clear();
  }

  /**
   * Call to release the resources used by VisualizerView. Like with the
   * MediaPlayer it is good practice to call this method
   */
  public void release()
  {
    mVisualizer.release();
  }

  /**
   * Pass data to the visualizer. Typically this will be obtained from the
   * Android Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener call back. See
   * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onWaveFormDataCapture }
   * @param bytes
   */
  public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
    mBytes = bytes;
    invalidate();
  }

  /**
   * Pass FFT data to the visualizer. Typically this will be obtained from the
   * Android Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener call back. See
   * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onFftDataCapture }
   * @param bytes
   */
  public void updateVisualizerFFT(byte[] bytes) {
    mFFTBytes = bytes;
    invalidate();
  }

  boolean mFlash = false;

  /**
   * Call this to make the visualizer flash. Useful for flashing at the start
   * of a song/loop etc...
   */
  public void flash() {
    mFlash = true;
    invalidate();
  }

  Bitmap mCanvasBitmap;
  Canvas mCanvas;


  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Create canvas once we're ready to draw
    mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    if(mCanvasBitmap == null)
    {
      mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    if(mCanvas == null)
    {
      mCanvas = new Canvas(mCanvasBitmap);
    }

    if (mBytes != null) {
      // Render all audio renderers
      AudioData audioData = new AudioData(mBytes);
      for(Renderer r : mRenderers)
      {
        r.render(mCanvas, audioData, mRect);
      }
    }

    if (mFFTBytes != null) {
      // Render all FFT renderers
      FFTData fftData = new FFTData(mFFTBytes);
      for(Renderer r : mRenderers)
      {
        r.render(mCanvas, fftData, mRect);
      }
    }

    // Fade out old contents
     mCanvas.drawPaint(mFadePaint);

    if(mFlash)
    {
      mFlash = false;
      mCanvas.drawPaint(mFlashPaint);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mCanvasBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
  }
}
```

See this

[image]

Comment: Did you resolved this issue? I also want to remove this fading effect. I want the bar to go away instantly.

Answer (score -1):

```
mFlashPaint.setColor(Color.argb(122, 255, 255, 255));
mFadePaint.setColor(Color.argb(122, 255, 255, 255)); // original is Color.argb(238, 255, 255, 255)); // Adjust alpha to change how quickly the image fades
mFadePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));  //original mode is  MULTIPLY

==>

mFlashPaint.setColor(Color.argb(122, 255, 255, 255));
mFadePaint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0)); // Adjust alpha to change how quickly the image fades
// mFadePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));
```